# Enabling the Duplicate Management in an Old Org

Tags: duplicate-management, setup, duplicate-matching-rule

Has anyone had the issue of NOT having the Duplicate Management feature installed on your org because the org was created before the Spring 2015 release?

I have a 2G Managed Package that I need to install on a Org that was bought in 2007.  Now, I realized, the managed package fails to install because the Potential Duplicates components is not available on the Org.

I looked everywhere to see if it is something that I can install myself. I contacted customer service but I have to wait for a couple of days since this org does not have premier support.

Does anyone know if this is something that we Admins can install on our own?